# «Исполняющий обязанности» — правильное сокращение

Tags: орфография, сокращения

Как правильно написать сокращенно: "Исполняющий обязанности главного бухгалтера"?

Answer (score 1):

А что тут надо сокращать? 
Если это для подписи, то можно И.о. Главбуха. Хотя если документ серьёзный, то лучше все-таки "И.О. главного бухгалтера", поскольку "главбух" - сокращение сугубо разговорное. В остальных случаях вообще не вижу необходимости для каких-либо сокращений.

Answer (score 1):

Если это начало предложения или это реквизит подписи, то согласно инструкции по делопроизводству правильно: *И. о. главного бухгалтера*.

Обращаю внимание, что необходимо наличие пробелов между сокращениями слов.
Однако стоит помнить, что все должности пишутся со строчной (маленькой) буквы, кроме высших государственных должностей. Поэтому ***и. о.*** можно писать с маленькой, если находится в центре предложений.

― Там к уголовной ответственности привлечён **и. о.** начальника Магаданского погранотряда подполковник Кострюков. [Марина Гриднева. За взятку — сажать! // «Московский комсомолец» в Нижнем Новгороде, 2004.07.30]

[Как правильно сокращать слова?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/86-rubric-100)

Comment: Приветствую Вас на сайте, Павел! Мне понравился ваш ответ. Для полноты можно добавить ссылку и пример. Хотите — сделаю? Будет красивый, ценный ответ, без каких-либо вопросов.

Answer (score 0):

Так "**И**.**о**. главного бухгалтера" или "**И**.**О**. главного бухгалтера"?

Думаю, что правильно "И.о. главного бухгалтера" или "и.о. главного бухгалтера" (в зависимости от того в начале предложения или нет), что и подтверждается практикой оформления деловых бумаг.